# Kotlin: How do I call a DialogFragment from within an Adapter class?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, adapter, dialogfragment

I have a MainAdapter.kt class that handles a RecyclerView. In its Holder class, I use a OnLongClickListener that calls a function deleteCategory(categoryId) to delete an entry in my Firebase database. This works perfectly:

```
class CategoryHolder(val customView: View, var category: Category? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customView) {
    private val TAG = CategoryHolder::class.java.simpleName

    fun bind(category: Category) {
        with(category) {
            customView.textView_name?.text = category.name
            customView.textView_description?.text = category.description

            val categoryId = category.id

            customView.setOnClickListener {
                    // do something
            }

            customView.setOnLongClickListener(
                    {
                       deleteCategory(categoryId)
                       true
                    }
            )
        }
    }

    private fun deleteCategory(categoryId: String) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

        val myRef = database.getReference("categories").child(categoryId)
        myRef.removeValue()
        Log.d(TAG, "Category with id " + categoryId + " deleted")
    }
}
```

But I rather want to call a function inside a DialogFragment class instead of the deleteCategory(id) function, like this:

```
  // Create an instance of a DeleteCategoryDialogFragment and show it
  fun showDeleteCategoryDialog(view: View, categoryId: String) {
      val dialog = DeleteCategoryDialogFragment.newInstance(categoryId)
      dialog.show(this@MainActivity.supportFragmentManager, 
      "DeleteCategoryDialog")
  }
```

This gives me a "Unresolved reference: @MainActivity" error.
How can I solve this? Is there a way to get hold of categoryId (of type String) in my MainActivity? This would allow me to move the function showDeleteCategoryDialog to MainActivity and solve the problem.

Comment: Where do you define the `showDeleteCategoryDialog()` function? Inside the adapter?

Comment: Yes, because I need to provide a value for categoryId, a String that I retrieve in the bind function of my CategoryHolder. The showDeleteCategoryDialog() function works fine when defined in MainActivity and provided with a 'fake' categoryId.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not refer to your `MainActivity` like your code above. You have to cast the `context` of your `ViewHolder` as `MainActivity` before using it:

```
val activity =  itemView.context as? MainActivity
// then you can show your dialog with activity?.supportFragmentManager
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to create a callback to this action and implement this callback on your MainActivity and create the dialog direct on your activity.

```
interface ClickListener {
    fun onLongClickListener(categoryId: Int)
}
```

then

```
class CategoryHolder(val customView: View, var category: Category? = null, var mListener: ClickListener?)

...
customView.setOnLongClickListener({
      mListener?.onLongClickListener(categoryId)
      ...
}
```

and on your MainActivity:

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, ClickListener {

    override fun onLongClickListener(categoryId: Int) {
     // Create your dialog
    }


    ...
        /* when creating your adapter you need to pass the listener to
         * adapter, so it can be used on your viewholder
         * mElements are the category elements, 'this' is the impl of
         * the adapter that was implemented here
        */
        mAdapter = CategoryAdapter(mElements, this)
 }
```

on your Adapter:

```
class CategoryAdapter(var mElements: List<Category>, var mListener: ClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<> ...

     // When creating your viewHolder
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryHolder {
        return CategoryHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context) 
            .inflate(R.layout.category_row, parent, false), listener)
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error in my onCreateViewHolder function: "No value passed for parameter mListener"

Comment: After implementing this listener in the MainActivity, you need to pass the activity as a new parameter on the ViewHolder constructor...
Now you need to create your ViewHolder like
`val holder = CategoryHolder(customView, category, listener)`

Comment: Now you need to pass the listener when creating the viewholder...
`override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryHolder { return CategoryHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context) .inflate(R.layout.category_row, parent, false), listener) } `

You can create this listener on your adapter and pass the listener to the ViewHolder when creating it

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps i've updated my answer, is it easier now? :D

Comment: I'm afraid, this does not help. My MainAdapter is of type FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that does not work on a list holding elements and categoryId is of type String, not Int.

Answer (score 0):

Here is, in detail, how this was solved:

1. In class CategoryHolder

   ```
   customView.setOnLongClickListener(
       {
         showDeleteCategoryDialog(it, categoryId)
         true
       } 
   )
   ```
2. In function showDeleteCategoryDialog

   ```
   // Create an instance of a DeleteCategoryDialogFragment and show it
   fun showDeleteCategoryDialog(view: View, categoryId: String) {
       val activity = itemView.context as? MainActivity
       val dialog = DeleteCategoryDialogFragment.newInstance(categoryId)
       dialog.show(activity?.supportFragmentManager, "DeleteCategoryDialog")
   }
   ```